# Automapping a wrapped class

Tags: automapper

We want to generically map from one database's context.tableType to another
e.g. UatDb.Branch--LiveDb.Branch

The table's are identical so no MapFrom is necessary.

The following generic mapping definition is sufficient

```
Mapper.CreateMap<TFromContextTableType,TToContextTableType>();
```

However!!!

We need to wrap the source context.tableType in the following wrapper class:

```
public class SWrapper<TFrom> where TFrom : class
{
        public SWrapper(TFrom model)
        {
            Model = model;
        }
        public TFrom Model { get; private set; }
}
```

Now to perform the mapping we have to map as follows:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SWrapper<FromBranchType>, ToBranchType>().ConstructUsing(x => new        Live.Branch()))
.ForMember(d => d.BranchID, o => o.MapFrom(x => x.Model.BranchID))
.ForMember(d => d.BranchName, o => o.MapFrom(x => x.Model.BranchName))
.ForMember(d => d.BranchCountry, o => o.MapFrom(x => x.Model.BranchCountry))
```

This means that we cannot generically map and have to explicitly declare a ForMember for each mapping. I can't figure out any solution using Resolvers or Type Converters.

I thought about perhaps wrapping the target in a SWrapper then resolving the returned Wrapped object to return the internal Product but not sure how to perform this.

All ideas welcome....

Comment: Does the destination type have to be placed in this wrapper as well?  You stated only the source type is wrapped.  If so, why not just do your Mapper.Map call on source.Model?

Comment: No Patrick, only the source needs to be wrapped.

Comment: @ElBauldo I know you asked this a long time ago. Take a look at my revised answer. I'm sure you found a solution quite some time ago. The extension method in my answer removes the need for hand written mapping to the wrapped Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking from your mapping you could do the following which does not require you to enter all of the property mappings by hand. The helper method in the second test allows for specialized mapping that you may not need.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Given_a_wrapper_class_I_should_be_able_to_unwrap_it_and_continue_with_mappings()
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<Wrapper<Source>, Destination>()
          .UnwrapUsing<Wrapper<Source>, Source, Destination>(w => w.Model)
          .ForMember(d => d.Bar, o => o.MapFrom(d => d.Baz));

    var source = new Source { Baz = 1, Foo = "One" };
    var wrapped = new Wrapper<Source> { Model = source };
    var destination = Mapper.Map<Destination>(wrapped);

    Assert.IsNotNull(destination);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, destination.Bar);
    Assert.AreEqual("One", destination.Foo);
}

public static class AutoMapperExtensions
{
    public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDest> UnwrapUsing<TWrapper, TSource, TDest>(this IMappingExpression<TWrapper, TDest> expr, Func<Wrapper<TSource>, TSource> unwrapper)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Wrapper<TSource>, TDest>()
              .ConstructUsing(x => Mapper.Map<TSource, TDest>(unwrapper(x)));

        return Mapper.CreateMap<TSource, TDest>();
    }
}

public class Source
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public int Baz { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Wrapper<T>
{
    public T Model { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This worked great for me. The only thing to watch out for is that automapper validation via Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid() will fail for the wrapper mappings. To fix this you can either call ForAllMembers(x => x.Ignore()) on the wrapper mapping, or what I did for further flexibility was to iterate all the mappings after setting them up and ignore the ones that were configured in either the wrapper or the base mapping.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a little utility method to your wrapper class:

```
public TDest MapTo<TDest>()
{
    return Mapper.Map<TFrom, TDest>(this.Model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Patrick but that would break 'separation of concerns'. At the moment, I've gone ahead and mapped all items long hand for want of a better solution.